# Append to child ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I want to append li to the child ul but I don't know why this doesn't work. I have html tag:

```
<ul class="role_module">
    <ul class="role_permission"></ul>
</ul>
```

and this javascript:

```
if (response) {
    $('ul.role_module').empty();

    $.each(response, function (module, value) {
        $("ul.role_module").append($("<li>").text(module));

        $.each(this, function (permission, value) {
            $("ul.role_permission").append($("<li>").text(permission));
        });

    });
 } else {
    alert('Error');
 }
```

I have array with data which looks like this:

```
array(2) {
   account => array(2) {
      account_view => 2
      account_edit => 2
   }
   admin => array(2) {
      admin_business_partner_view => 4
      admin_business_partner_edit => 4
}
```

And I want this result

- account

  - account_view
  - account_edit
- admin

  - admin_business_partner_view
  - admin_business_partner_edit

but instead of this I'm getting just this without any li child:

- account
- admin

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A `<ul>` directly inside another `<ul>` doesn't make sense. The inner `<ul>` should be inside a list element (`<li>`).

Comment: and what do you have in your response `{}` or `[]`?

Comment: @Pointy: I understand, and how can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: @Jai: response is json array

Comment: When you call empty it will remove the UL so you will not be finding that UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below code

Jquery

```
var obj = {
   'account': ['account_view' , 'account_edit'],
    'admin' : ['admin_business_partner_view' ,
      'admin_business_partner_edit']
}

$.each(obj, function (index, value) {    
    $("ul.role_module").append($("<li class='" + index + "'></li>" ).text(index));
    $("ul.role_module").append($("<ul class='role_permission'>"));
    $.each(value, function (permission, value1) {        
        $("li."  + index + "+ ul.role_permission").append($('<li></li>').text(value1));
    });
});
```

Html

```
<ul class="role_module">    
</ul>
```

Refer to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sahilgupta202/x1gcnLeu/)

**Update**

It is not gud practice to wrap a `ul` element inside another `ul`. Do get the same thing you should append the `child ul` element inside parent `li`.

Please refer to the [updated-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sahilgupta202/x1gcnLeu/1/)

Comment: Exactly I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are should to fix your javascript code to something like this:

```
if (response) {
    var $roleModule = $(".role_module");
    $roleModule.empty();

    $.each(response, function (module, value) {
        var $roleModuleItem = $("<li />").text(module).append($("<ul class='role_permission' />"));
            $roleModule.append($roleModuleItem);

        $.each(this, function (permission, value) {
            $roleModuleItem.find("ul").append($("<li />").text(permission));
        });

    });
 } else {
    alert('Error');
 }
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/apfsrgwb/)